# Postgres - query timeseries group by interval

Tags: sql, postgresql, grouping

I have a table- BusInfo which stores how many passengers get on the bus and how many seats he/she can occupy(1 or more depending on bags he/she has).
I have created a fiddle for it-

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/88226/11

```
start                        end                  bus_name  seats   start_time  ride_time
April, 28 2016 17:00:00 April, 28 2016 18:00:00   CA        2   1461862800      3600
April, 28 2016 17:30:00 April, 28 2016 18:30:00   CA        1   1461864600      3600
April, 28 2016 17:45:00 April, 28 2016 18:45:00   CA        2   1461865500      3600
April, 28 2016 17:00:00 April, 28 2016 19:00:00   CA        1   1461862800      7200
April, 28 2016 17:00:00 April, 28 2016 17:30:00   CA        2   1461862800      1800
```

I want to run a query which gets the seat occupancy at 10 min interval.Something like this is the expected output

```
datetime |  seats occupied at the time
17:00   5
17:10   5
17:20   5
17:30   4
17:40   4
17:50   6
18:00   4
```

I tried group by but did not get any closer-

```
select to_char(to_timestamp(floor((extract('epoch' from to_timestamp(start_time))/ 600))*600),'yyyy/MM/dd HH24:MI'), 
              sum(seats) from businfo 

where start_time >= 1461862800 and start_time <= 1461866400 
and (start_time+ride_time) >= (1461862800)
group by to_char(to_timestamp(floor((extract('epoch' from     
to_timestamp(start_time))/ 600))*600),'yyyy/MM/dd HH24:MI')
order by to_char(to_timestamp(floor((extract('epoch' from   
      to_timestamp(start_time))/ 600))*600),'yyyy/MM/dd HH24:MI') ASC
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

One method uses `generate_series()`:

```
select gs.ts, sum(seats)
from generate_series('2016-04-28 17:00:00'::timestamp, '2016-04-28 18:00:00', interval '10 minute') gs(ts) join
     businfo bi
     on gs.ts between bi.start and bi.end
group by gs.ts
order by gs.ts;
```

Comment: thanks for your response. The query returns the expected results but it is very slow in spite of the fact that I do not have a really large database. How can i optimize it? May be start with adding indexes.

Comment: Could I suggest that you ask another question, explicitly about performance?